# Where is that syntax error on line 2?

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok, so in the following actionscript 3.0 code there is a syntax error on line 2, but i don't know what that is.
I'm a beginner so could someone please help me on this?

```
var numberToCast:Number;
```

on the following line there is a syntax error, says the compiler, and i haven't a clue what that is

```
for (numberToCast = –1; numberToCast<2; numberToCast++){ 

trace("Boolean(" + numberToCast +") is " + Boolean(numberToCast)); 

}
```

Comment: try this:  `for (var numberToCast = –1;`  - notice the var.  That should give you a different error though...

Comment: you are using the wrong subtraction symbol in the for loop `numberToCast = –1`, it should be just `numberToCast = -1`

Comment: Try replacing +") is " with + ") is " (I have added a space after +)

Comment: ok it worked after i have tried your suggestions, both of them, one after the other..
first i have tried the 'var' edit, and then another subtraction symbol, and it works now (without the 'var' keyword), and working now with all the subtraction symbols that can be found on my keyboard..?? lol
i still don't get it thouhh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `-` (numberToCast = **–1**;),  it's not actually the minus symbol. Probably a symptom of copying and pasting (out of Microsoft Office maybe? Word is bad for replacing the minus with a dash)

And as per my comment, you will need to define (`var`) `numberToCast` (either prior to the loop or in the loop declaration) or you'll get a different error after fixing the minus.

Comment: Ok so it's solved it turns out the problem was with that dash/subtraction symbol mix up.